# How to tell a dupe question?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

There is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48928503/285587) that seems to me an exemplary duplicate for the [well-known post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) with a lot of detailed answers which scarcely can be surpassed, especially by a two links-only answer.

But as far as I can tell, nobody else thinks it's a dupe. So, am I taking it wrong?

Or, if put it in other words: What is exactly genuinely new in the question and what is the useful and original content in the answers?

Comment: I don't see what's so different from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48933793/1415724) where you submitted your own answer. Now *that* is classic "the pot calling the kettle black" if you ask me.

Comment: *"What is exactly genuinely new in the question and what is the useful and original content in the answers?"* - The fact that `delete *` isn't the proper for MySQL [DELETE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html) maybe? Or that maybe... just maybe they wanted to delete the entire table and thought that by using the same syntax as `SELECT *` would actually delete the entire contents? Have you not thought about that? And the fact that you are known to not use the proper additional duplicates that should have been added? You have done this many times where I flagged for moderation.

Comment: I voted to close this meta post as unclear, because it is unclear what your intentions are and why you would want to close a question in the first place, given the original post and where you get off on posting an answer for a [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48933793/1415724).

Comment: Why don't you just vote to close it if you think it's a duplicate?

Comment: @DonaldDuck:  [They already did.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363712/how-to-tell-a-dupe-question/363713#comment559705_363715)

Answer (score 2):

If the answers to the potential target question can be applied to the subject question, then it's probably a duplicate. It's not sufficient but it is necessary.

There's no reason why everyone would agree on whether something's a duplicate or not so the fact that you apparently disagree with other users is not a problem.

If it's just that they've not seen what you can see and eventually there'll be other close votes.

If you're wrong then your close vote will age away with no harm done.

Comment: So that's the question I am asking - why there are no other votes? What is exactly genuinely new in the question and what is the useful and original content in the answers?

Comment: @YourCommonSense I don't think I can answer that as I'm not a php expert. Perhaps it's up to you (assuming you are a php expert) to make the case for it being a duplicate.

Comment: @ChrisF:  He cast a binding dupe closure vote, which was undone by a binding dupe reopen vote.

Comment: Then the system is working.

Answer (score -2):

The question's *ever so slightly different*.

The OP is asking whether or not they're safe in allowing that query to go through.  The candidate duplicate is asking how they can prevent unsafe queries from going through their application.

These two issues are joined at the hip, but they are not the same thing.  They're approaching it from different angles.  The answer to the question is, "No, it's not safe, use parameterized queries instead," and that's a *fine* answer.

Comment: Answers in the existing question do tell exactly the same, "it is not safe" and even explain why it is so and tell to use prepared statements and offer examples. The OP should be 100% satisfied  with existing answers. Why there should be another one? Besides, isn't a question "isn't my code safe" an off topic?

Comment: @YourCommonSense:  I skimmed the question, and in frankness, the SQL injection isn't the *only* thing going on there.  I'm not party to the PHP group, so I leave the moderation in their hands.  I'm only commenting as a relatively outside observer, and providing a reason why I personally wouldn't vote to close as a dupe.

Comment: Anything that *isn't the only thing going on there* is outright off topic and deserve a comment at most.

Comment: Here's a thought:  why not invite the person that undid your moderation efforts to this meta question?  My primary suspicion here is that you're upset with their decision.  Again, **I'm only seeing what I would see as an outside observer**, and I largely don't think it's 100% a dupe.

Comment: @YourCommonSense surely you can find a PHP question that is more specifically about "Is this code open to SQL injection?". Its just a poorly researched question in a long line of poorly researched questions.

Comment: @YourCommonSense That isn't the first time you mess up closing with improper duplicates. You also seem to have your own views on not closing questions and posting your own answer as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48933793/1415724) with your own answer. As I said [in a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363712/how-to-tell-a-dupe-question#comment559918_363712) up there, and as the expression goes: *"that's the pot calling the kettle black"*, remember that one.

Comment: *"Here's a thought: why not invite the person that undid your moderation efforts to this meta question?"* - @Makoto That is a **great** idea!! **BUT**, you see and here's the clincher; the guy doesn't want to have anything to do with me, where I actually posted worthy and "on topic" comments where he just ignored them outright. So as you can probably tell, this is a "personal" thing for him on me. I'm not making this up. Instead, someone else did it for him under the answer I gave.